# Angular - Optimize Vendor bundle

Tags: angular, types, webpack

Below is snapshot for my vendor.js bundle using **webpack-bundle-modifier**

[image]

Mine is a not-so-complex application, using essential modules - angular, rxjs, prime-ng, bootstrap, etc. However size of bundle is already **4.65**MB. Why is it so?

Can somebody please suggest me if any of below would help (and how much) to improve on bundle size,

- AOT
- Tree-shaking
- Code-Splitting

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, size of boxes represent size of modules, right? If yes, then looks like you are using just too many components. look at size of toastr-service is almost as big as whole @angular package. Consider development your own components designed for your needs. I'm almost 100% sure that you are not even using 50% or possibilites of those packages.

Comment: @PatrykBrejdak Won't treeshaking help removing unused components from referenced packages?

Comment: Actually it depends on imports. For example if you are importing `module` in `anuglar module` with `forRoot()` then it won't be removed. However since `webpack 2` if I'm not mistaken there is automatically tree shaking. Try while building use flag `--build-optimizer` (tree-shaking) and `--vendor-chunk=true` (prevent from bundling main.js with vendor.js)